# How can that question be an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I've found that hmmm "answer": https://stackoverflow.com/a/340216/531954

> "How can you assure me your code is 100% free of bugs?"

I've flagged it as "not an answer" but my flag was refused, and the moderator has written that flags shouldn't be used "to indicate technical inaccuracies". Hmmm, what technical inaccuracies, I don't see nothing "technical" in  that answer, well, I don't see even an answer there, it's simply a question.

Well, maybe it was thought to be a funny **comment**, but how come it be, that that's considered a fully qualified answer, and what's more, a valuable one?

Comment: do you mean you flagged it as "Not an answer"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to flag an answer as "it is not an answer"?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer)

Answer (score 6):

It does answer the question, though. The question asks for examples of when they've encountered the halting problem. That's an example. Ergo, an answer. If you don't like terrible answers like that, maybe you should be targeting the terrible question...

Comment: It is indeed an answer, true, but I'm not sure I agree 100% with your last sentence. IMHO we should not tolerate bad answers to bad questions, in the same way we don't exonerate a murderer because they killed another murderer.

Comment: I don't see how that could be an example for the halting problem.

Comment: @Don, please prove to me the last few thousand lines of code you wrote are free of any bug, now and in the future. Go ahead, I'll be waiting :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi you've mistaken halting problem with computational hard problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi If it never answered the question, then yes, we should delete it whether the question sucks or not. But this is not the case here. We have a legitimate attempt to answer the question, so there's no reason to delete the answer. The question, perhaps.

Comment: @Don, I believe the complexity of determining whether a given program will run forever or not is the same as determining whether it will give correct results forever or not. But that's just me.

Comment: @animuson, I do agree, I was just pointing out that, in the general case, ignoring a bad answer to focus on the bad question that "triggered" it only affects half the problem. We have to educate answerers too :)

Comment: @animuson hmm I'm curious what constitutes a legitimate attempt to answer a question? If something is complete gibberish, how can you prove that it wasn't a legitimate attempt which had obviously failed?

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt The point you are making indicates that it is a bad answer, not that it is not an answer. If I ask for the sum of "2+2" and someone says "3", that's a bad answer but still an answer. If someone says "why are you asking?" that's not an answer.

Comment: @Louis, yes, I've already noticed the irony in that situation. A correct answer could be deleted because it's only a comment. A wrong answer can't be deleted because it's a failed attemt to create a correct answer.

Comment: *If you don't like terrible answers like that, maybe you should be targeting the terrible question* -- +1

Answer (score 6):

It is an answer. You can read it as:

> [I ran into the halting problem in the field when my boss/coworker asked:] "How can you assure me your code is 100% free of bugs?"

The answerer decided to just provide the example, without the introduction I added in brackets. So this answer is written in a way that is likely to make it appear to be a non-answer to reviewers. It does look like a comment, but it is still an answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: I see. So my flag was refused because it's a wrong example of a halting problem? What an irony, if the answer would be in some way correct, it would be deleted...